# Yaml key value updation in jenkins pipeline groovy script

Tags: groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, snakeyaml

I want to update yaml key and value without taking in a variable and then modify and after that saving on new file.
this is groovy script pipeline of jenkins.

```
                pipeline {
                    agent any

                    environment {
                        buildNumber = "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                        BUILD_DATE = getCurrentBuildDate()
                    }

                    parameters {
                        string(
                            name: 'COUNTER',
                            defaultValue: '5',
                            description: 'Enter the new value'
                        )
                        string(
                            name: 'TOprefix',
                            defaultValue: "RT_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}_June_${env.BUILD_DATE}",
                            description: 'Enter the TO count'
                        )
                        string(
                            name: 'LOAD_PROFILE',
                            defaultValue: 'guestsupply',
                            description: 'This is Load Profile'
                        )
                    }

                    stages {
                        stage('Modify YAML') {
                            steps {
                                script {
                                    // Retrieve the parameterized values
                                    def parameterValue = params.COUNTER
                                    def parameterValue1 = params.TOprefix
                                    def parameterValue2 = params.LOAD_PROFILE + '_profile'

                                    // Load the YAML file
                                    def yamlFile = readYaml file: 'profile_properties.yaml'

                                    // Modify the desired key with the parameter value
                                    yamlFile[parameterValue2].TO_count = parameterValue
                                    yamlFile[parameterValue2].TOprefix = parameterValue1

                                    println parameterValue2

                                    // Delete the existing file
                                    sh 'rm -f profile_properties.yaml'

                                    // Save the updated YAML back to the file
                                    writeYaml file: 'profile_properties.yaml', data: yamlFile
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stage('Automation Script'){
                            steps {
                                
                                    sh 'automated-script.sh'
                                    
                                }

                        }
                    }
                    
                }

                def getCurrentBuildDate() {
                    def dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd")
                    return dateFormat.format(new Date())
                }
```

I want pipeline script with only updating one yaml key and value pair not creating any new file beacause recreate the file it will take more processing power